# Custom view is not visible when adding it programatically, but it's visible when it's added using storyboards

Tags: ios, swift

I have my own custom view that acts like a progress bar. Here is the code for it:

```
class ProgressBar: UIView {

    var bottomProgressBar = CAShapeLayer()
    var topProgressBar = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        bottomProgressBar.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        bottomProgressBar.opacity = 0.1
        bottomProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height
        bottomProgressBar.strokeStart = 0
        bottomProgressBar.strokeEnd = 1
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomProgressBar)

        topProgressBar.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        topProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height
        topProgressBar.strokeStart = 0
        topProgressBar.strokeEnd = 1
        self.layer.addSublayer(topProgressBar)

        animate(toValue: 0)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))

        bottomProgressBar.path = path.cgPath
        topProgressBar.path = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

Now, when I add this using storyboards, by adding an `UIView` inside the controller and setting the `Custom Class` to `ProgressBar` I can see it visible when running the app (it should have a white color with alpha 0.1).

But when I'm trying to added programatically , it's not visible at all. Only if I explicitly set the background color:

```
myProgressBar.backgroudColor = .red
```

This is not what I want. I want it to have the white color and alpha 0.1 that is the initial value.

Here is my code for adding it programatically:

```
var progressBar = ProgressBar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(progressBar)

        progressBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: progressBar, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: progressBar, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: progressBar, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: progressBar, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 1).isActive = true
    }
```

I don't seem to understand what is the difference between adding it using storyboards and adding it programatically.
I see that the constraints are correct and the view is added, but why doesn't the default color appear ?

Does anyone have an idea what my issue is in this case ?

edit:

Added code for the `animate` method:

```
func animate(toValue: Double) {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

    animation.duration = 1.0
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = toValue

    topProgressBar.strokeEnd = CGFloat(toValue)
    topProgressBar.animation(forKey: "animate")
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend double-checking the constraints, if you take a screenshot​ in emulator, it might exist but not be on screen or the proper size

Comment: I put the same constraints in code as in storyboard where it works. If I change the color to red, I can see them, perfect. But that is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem starts with this `var progressBar = ProgressBar()`. This invokes the init method and `configure()` is called. At this point `ProgressBar` frame width and height is `zero`.

In your `configure()` method your are setting line widths.

```
bottomProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height // 0
topProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height // 0
```

So lines width are set to `zero` and thats way it's not being displayed.

To fix this you must update the `CAShapeLayer` line widths in `layoutSubviews()` method.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))

    bottomProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height // Update lineWidth
    topProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height    // Update lineWidth

    bottomProgressBar.path = path.cgPath
    topProgressBar.path = path.cgPath
}
```

Why it works for storyboard? Because frame has been set already before `configure` is called. You can print the frame size in `configure` and see the difference in both scenarios.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working now. I will award the bounty when it becomes eligible.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a bug in display for custom views, You can add this to `viewDidLoad`

```
 self.progressBar.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Edit:

you can add this line to configure method default background color for the view as the default is transparent

```
 self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

I see all colors are white so it's usual not to see anything

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, even if I add that line .

Comment: what's inside that animate(toValue: 0)

Comment: I updated the question with the code. I also try to delete that line inside configure() and still is the same issue. So I am not sure that there is a problem with that method.

Comment: it's not a good practice to add animation while you configure the view for display , If you can move that code to viewDidAppear of the mainViewController

Comment: Still, same issue. Not sure else can I do.

Comment: even red color in config

Comment: oh wait, I can see it if I set it to white. But the opacity is not set to 0.1. It's 1. So it;s just like setting the background color in the MainVC. The progress bar doesn;t work. It just has a background color and thats it.

Comment: When I use storyboards, the View has the background color set to .clear. So that way I can see my progress bar real colors. But in code doesn't work this way.